# What's the meaning of "it was a tidy bow"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning

I found this expression in a [news article](https://www.msn.com/en-ca/news/world/a-plan-to-defeat-coronavirus-finally-emerges-but-its-not-from-the-white-house/ar-BB12rZuW):

> When Vermont’s first coronavirus case was detected last month, it took two state health workers a day to track down 13 people who came into contact with that single patient. They put them under quarantine and started monitoring for symptoms. No one else became sick.
>
> **“It was a tidy bow,”** recalled Daniel Daltry, one of the two health officers who did the work.
>
> Within days, new cases were “coming in like dominoes,” Daltry said. By late March, his team was racing on a single day to trace the contacts of 12 patients, when an additional 30 cases landed on their desk.

I tried but couldn't find any dictionary entry or good explanation for the phrase. I guess, from the context, it could mean something manageable or doable, but otherwise I have no clue.

This is my first post on this forum. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My *guess* is that it's an allusion to putting a tidy bow on a present: that is to say, they got everything "wrapped up" (finished) nicely.

I can find very few references to this phrase outside of literal tidy bows, but one similar (but not identical) usage is [here](https://www.gyroscopereview.com/2020/11/killing-pesky-cliches/), in which the writer seemingly uses it to refer to getting their task (in this case, a poem) done:

> In their haste to put a tidy bow at the end of the poem, the poet wraps it up with a cliché.

All that said, I've never personally heard anyone use this phrase before.

Comment: Google ngram has no occurrences of tidy bow. Your explanation is clear, analogically convincing and likely correct.

Comment: Yeah it does. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tidy+bow&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctidy%20bow%3B%2Cc0) and *"all wrapped up with a tidy bow"*, in quotes, has 468 hits on Google. I can't place it but I've heard it, and there's half a chance I've said it.

Comment: Probably correct, and with a real attempt to provide supporting evidence. 'Wrapped up' is of course a well-known metaphor. 'Coming in like dominoes' is more dubious. _Covered in spots_?